# Transitions to new record

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to transition to a newly created record. I can create it ok, fill it in and save it on the server, but when it comes to `this.transitionToRoute( 'app', this.get( 'content' ) );` I get a console error:

> Uncaught Error: assertion failed: You are trying to look up a
>   controller that you did not define, and for which Ember does not know
>   the model.

This is not a controller for a route, so you must explicitly define the controller (WEM.AppsCreateAppController) or pass a model as the second parameter to `controllerFor`, so that Ember knows which type of controller to create for you.`

I understand what the errors is telling me, just not sure where I went wrong. Here's the (what I think is) relevant code:

```
WEM.CreateAppController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  startEditing: function() {
        console.log( 'start' );
        this.transaction = this.get( 'store' ).transaction();
        this.set( 'content', this.transaction.createRecord( WEM.App, {} ) );
    },

    stopEditing: function() {
        console.log( 'stop' );
        if ( this.transaction ) {
            this.transaction.rollback();
            this.transaction = null;
        }
    },

    save: function() {
        console.log( 'save' );
        this.transaction.commit();
        this.transaction = null;
    },

    transitionAfterSave: function() {
        console.log( 'trans' );
        if ( this.get('content.id' ) ) {
            console.log(this.get( 'content' ));
            this.transitionToRoute( 'app', this.get( 'content' ) );
        }
    }.observes( 'content.id' ),

    cancel: function() {
        console.log( 'cancel' );
        this.stopEditing();
        this.transitionToRoute( 'apps' );
    }
});
```

Here are my routes

```
WEM.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource( 'apps', { path: '/' }, function(){
        this.resource( 'create_app', { path: 'apps/new' } );
        this.resource( 'app', { path: 'app/:app_id'}, function(){
            this.resource( 'settings', { path: 'settings' } );
            this.resource( 'error', { path: 'error/:error_id' } );
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post also the code of the router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like there is something wrong with the `app` route. Are you able to transition to it with an existing record? For example, change

```
transitionAfterSave: function() {
    console.log( 'trans' );
    if ( this.get('content.id' ) ) {
        console.log(this.get( 'content' ));
        this.transitionToRoute( 'app', WEM.App.find(1) );
    }
}.observes( 'content.id' ),
```

Assuming you have an App with id=1 and you have an `app/:app_id` route this should work. If not you can debug problem with app route without worrying about new records.

Comment: Doing that gave me the same error so I assume it's something to do with my routes? I've updated the question to include them.

Comment: At first glance i'm thinking the `app` resource should not be nested under `apps` - try moving it to root?

Comment: or rather remove "app" from the path value (or change it to "apps", but there's really no need to use the absolute path in your nested routes all the time).